# Rolling calculations with lag and ifelse

Tags: r, dataframe, cumulative-sum

I'm trying to calculate the cumulative sum of a column in my data frame, but I only want it to be done based on a condition.

I am very new to R and trying to convert this spss code below in R to achieve the dataframe below with a new column called cumulative based on whether the lca is the same as the row above and if it is then add health net cost to the cumulative cost above.

```
spss code:
IF LAG(LCA) NE LCA cumulative=health_net_cost.
IF LAG(LCA)=LCA cumulative=LAG(cumulative)+health_net_cost.
EXECUTE.
```

Dataframe in R

```
Lca health_net_cost   cummulative
10  100         100     
10  200         300
10  300         600
28  400         1000
28  100         1100
8   100         1200
8   200         1400
8   300         1700
```

Comment: Hi, Welcome to SO! Here are some [guidelines](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) for how to ask and format questions. It's always a good idea to include code for what you've tried so far. And you could also provide more usable sample data by using the ```dput()``` function (see the help file by running ```?dput``` in the console) with your data.frame and copy-pasting that output to your question with the 'edit' link.

Answer (score 1):

This  may the solution you looking for your problem.
Using cumsum function.

```
df <- data.frame("LCA" = c(10,10,10,28,28,8,8,8),"Health_Net_Cost" = c(100,200,300,400,100,100,200,300))
df
```

Output:

```
LCA Health_Net_Cost
10            100
10            200
10            300
28            400
28            100
 8            100
 8            200
 8            300
```

Run:

```
cum_df <- df%>%group_by(LCA)%>%mutate(Cumulative=cumsum(Health_Net_Cost))
cum_df
```

Yours expected output:

```
LCA Health_Net_Cost Cumulative
10             100        100
10             200        300
10             300        600
28             400        400
28             100        500
 8             100        100
 8             200        300
 8             300        600
```

Comment: This looks an awful lot like the edited answer i've just posted ...

Comment: Yeah, I read the OP comment and modified the previous answer.

Comment: Yes! This is just co incident. enjoy :-)

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT**:

If you want the cumulative sums **grouped by `LCA`**, this may help:

```
install.packages("dplyr")
library(dplyr)
df %>%
  group_by(LCA) %>%
  mutate("cumulative" = cumsum(Health_Net_Cost))
# A tibble: 8 x 3
# Groups:   LCA [3]
    LCA Health_Net_Cost cumulative
  <dbl>           <dbl>      <dbl>
1    10             100        100
2    10             200        300
3    10             300        600
4    28             400        400
5    28             100        500
6     8             100        100
7     8             200        300
8     8             300        600
```

Comment: Thanks -  I produced the wrong dataframe above and I am so new to this site so I dont know how to add an R dataframe into my comment.  What I want is roughly the same above but if the lca doesnt match the lca above then the cumulative cost would be the health net cost for the first lca - e.g the first lca "8" the cumulative cost would be 100.

Comment: So you want the cumulative costs **grouped by LCA**?

Comment: Plz see updated answer. Is this what you're looking for?